# Error with `python3.10` when running `apt install software-properties-common` when building dockerfile

Tags: python, linux, docker, ubuntu, apt

Currently my dockerfile is just:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
```

However when building the dockerfile and running the step `apt install software-properties-common -y` the following error is in the messages:

```
#0 41.07 Setting up python3.10-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04.2) ...
#0 41.16 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-310.pyc.139723958934016'dpkg: error processing package python3.10-minimal (--configure):
#0 41.16  installed python3.10-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
#0 41.17 Errors were encountered while processing:
#0 41.17  python3.10-minimal
#0 41.18 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt install software-properties-common -y]: exit code: 100
```

Was wondering if you guys could please help me solve this error in order to finish building the dockerfile?

Comment: That yields ` > [3/4] RUN sudo apt install software-properties-common -y:                                              
#0 0.301 /bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found `

Comment: Adding `RUN apt-get -y install sudo` and then running `RUN sudo apt install software-properties-common -y ` yields the same error as my original first post.

Comment: The process is running as root, so sudo does absolutely nothing except add confusion. That's not the solution.

Comment: When I build your original Dockerfile (no sudo), it works and I don't get the error you do. Make sure you have the latest ubuntu image locally by doing `docker pull ubuntu:latest`. And make sure you're not running out of disk space.

Comment: @HansKilian I have ran `docker pull ubuntu:latest` and am not running out of disk space but do still get the same error as my original first post. I am still not sure what is causing this error.

Comment: @HansKilian Thank you yes turns out it was the `snap` version of docker causing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had the `snap` version of docker and that caused the error but when I downloaded the `apt` version of docker from https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ there was no error.

Answer (score 0):

I saw exact same error. It appears to happen when a utility presents a Y/n prompt. The fix is to use the -y switch.

This Dockerfile compiles correctly

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y full-upgrade 
RUN apt-get -y install python3

RUN python3 --version
```